# Hide contact groups

Tags: contacts, google-contacts, contact-groups, people-app

Is it possible to hide some contact groups from the default People App?

I'm talking in particular about the default Google groups named "Family", "Friends" and "Coworkers"; since I don't use them, and in their stead I have added some other groups that are more useful to me, I'd like to remove or simply hide these default ones, in order to keep the list of groups less cluttered.

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1):

When you log into [Google Contacts](https://contacts.google.com) you can remove all such groups (and "circles") there. They will disappear from your app after synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible using the following navigation path:

1. Open *People* app
2. Tap the Overflow (menu icon)
3. Select *Contacts to Display* option
4. Select *Customize* option (at bottom of the list)
5. Select the appropriate Google account
6. Use checkboxes to select which categories are displayed

[image: Custom View Screenshot]

Comment: This is not what I have asked. I want to hide the actual groups, not the contacts.